# Copying new files to network drive in windows 7 gives me the error: Path does not exist

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, path, mapped-drive

I'm trying to save a new excel file on a network drive. I can access the drive, see all files, go through them but when i want to save my work from excel to this drive it gives me the error:Path does not exist. Please try again. I as well tried to move the file by dragging it from desktop to the mapped drive but it froze at first while trying to copy the file and then i was not able to even try to move it. And it only happens with this specific mapped drive because i'm able to save my work on the other drives.

Comment: do you have permission to save to that drive? maybe you only have read access. can you make a text file in notepad and save it there?

Comment: Yes, i've always been able to save to that drive. I saved a text file with no problem in root but after i try to save within folders and folders, the error appears. But it's weird because I've always been able to save within folders and i'm trying to save in the same folders that i always have done, with which i haven't had any problems before, until now.

Comment: You either have a permissions issue (is this a work network drive)? Or the UNC path is too long over 255 characters. If the fully qualified path name is too long, you can have problems too.

Comment: Yes, a work network drive but days before i was able to copy without problems on this path and i haven't add another folder to it so that's the confusing part because i can access the mapped drive and also save a text file or any other file in root but not within this folder but as you say it may be too long but again, i have saved files before on this path without problems so it's strange that now the cause would be that the path it's too long.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because to localized and work environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at first we took the computer out of the domain because a message appeared at login saying that the workstation didn't have relationship with domain and so after this we add it again to the domain and it seemed to work just for a bit but after trying to save files through excel  the problem occurred again we could just only drag the files to the mapped drive  and then the workstation message appeared again so at the end the problem was that i forgot to change the user password and it was already past due date so after changing it all started working again. So this was generating the conflict and not allowing me to login while connected to Ethernet cable because I had to remove it so I could enter with the old password then I would plugged it back once I was logged in to have access to the network and of course this was generating as well the mapped drive conflict.